# Ordernar por valor no DataTables

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, jsp

Estou usando o Bootstrap SB Admin2, que faz uso do componente [DataTables](https://datatables.net/reference/option/).

Em minha página jsp estou carregando a seguinte tabela:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Código</th>
      <th>Nome RCA</th>
      <th>Meta</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <c:forEach var="rca" items="${listaTeste }">
      <tr class="odd gradeX">
        <td>${rca.codusur }</td>
        <td>${rca.nome }</td>
        <td style="text-align: right">${rca.meta }</td>
      </tr>
    </c:forEach>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

e o seguinte código para o javascript:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#dataTables-example').DataTable({
            responsive: true,
            "order": [2, 'asc']
    });
});
</script>
```

Dessa maneira o código funciona, resultado exemplo:

```
2512    Aa                         227,27
5769    Ma                       2.318,18
2945    Mb                       4.772,72
```

Porém, se peço uma formatação para a jstl dessa maneira:

```
<td style="text-align: right"><fmt:formatNumber value="${rca.meta }" type="currency" /></td>
```

A tabela fica ordenada assim:

```
5769    Ma                      R$ 2.318,18
2512    Aa                      R$   227,27
2945    Mb                      R$ 4.772,72
```

Pelo que percebi parece que ele está lendo como string, alguma solução para este caso? Já olhei a documentação e não achei nada.

**PS**: Peço desculpa pela extensão da pergunta, sou novo aqui, mas queria explicar todos os detalhes.

Tentei mudar o pattern no fmtNumber, usando `pattern="#,##0.00"`, e a classificação continuar errada, porém usando `pattern="0.00"` somente assim ele consegue classificar.

Comment: Tentou utilizar este plugin: http://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/currency?

Comment: Tentei, esse plugin já veio junto com o datatable. Apenas para ver se entendi: é ele que faria a formatação? Ou eu teria de tirar o fmt do código? Porque em ambos os casos não consegui fazer funcionar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correto não irá funcionar o código justamente devido a formatação do número, para você ordenar corretamente o formato do número deve estar em 0.00.

O que eu sugeriria para você seria o seguinte, inserir nos `td's` o valor já convertido utilizando a máscara 0.00 e reconfigurar a formatação de exibição na inicialização do `datatables`.

Dessa forma:

```
<td style="text-align: right"><fmt:formatNumber value="${rca.meta }" pattern="0.00" /></td>
```

E a inicialização do `datatables` ficaria, lembrando que você precisará adicionar o plugin de ordenação do `datatables`.

```
$('#dataTables-example').DataTable({
  //demais configurações
  "aoColumns": [
    //demais colunas
    { "sType": "numeric-comma" }, //aplica a máscara monetária
  ],
});
```

segue a referência para a lista de plugins: https://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/

Comment: Utilizando o numeric comma dá certo, tentei reconfigurar com formated number e com currency, porém não funciona, por hora irei deixar assim mesmo. Agradeço a ajuda.

Answer (score 1):

Nesse momento o plugin é capaz de lidar com este problema usando o atributo de linguagem para traduzir partes do sistema para o idioma nativo do sistema e para inserir configurações regionais, para contornar este problema utilize da seguinte forma.

```
$('#dataTables-example').DataTable( {
    "language": {
        "decimal": ",",
        "thousands": "."
    }
} );
```

Para maiores informações acesse o [link](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/comma-decimal.html)

Comment: sua solução funcionou pra mim!! valeuu